# How to reduce code duplication with private variables setting without using inheritance?

Tags: php, perl, oop, code-duplication

I have classes MonthTimeCard and MonthReport. They use same input field for choosing month, so the validation is the same and initialisation is the same.

```
class MonthTimeCard {

private function setPrivateVarsByUserInput()
    {
        $this->month_from_input = '2015-09';

        $this->date_from = '2015-09-01';
        $this->date_to = '2015-09-30';

        // lets say those 3 values are formated, validated and returned as array from MonthUserInput class.
        // but I have to repeat code in my both classes to initialize them
        // I could have one liner like $this->data = $this->monthUserInput->getInput();
        // but current class code will need to call $this->data->[variable] everywhere - not looking very nice,
        // because ->data is not usefull here, just extra characters.
    }

}

Class MonthReport {
    ... same initialisation
}
```

I now just hard coded them but you know assignment will be from return array of MonthUserInput class which will validate. There is only one user input field which gets string like '2015-09' and MonthUserInput class will add first day and last day of month.

I could avoid this if I would use inheritance but I have read that should avoid and some even say that it should be removed from OOP.

http://blogs.perl.org/users/sid_burn/2014/03/inheritance-is-bad-code-reuse-part-1.html

With inheritance I would simply in do validating and setting user input in parent class and so no duplication.

How should I do this now? Of course its just 3 variables in this example, I plan to have 5, its not much, but still its duplication and with inheritance there would not be duplication in this case.

**Update**

I would like to see explanation which I could use to explain to anybody who do not agree that inheritance would be bad to this situation. For example I discussed with one experienced programmer and he does not see a problem here to use inheritance for code reuse. I just said there is lot on internet telling that use composition, but that was not good argument for this situation.

For example:

> Favor composition over inheritance. If two classes don't have an "is
>   a" relationship, then it should never be necessary to use inheritance
>   to achieve code reuse. Never.

this would not be a good argument for some people. They can ask - who invented those rules and why? They do not see a problem by breaking this rule.

Comment: What language is this? Perl, PHP? Please add appropriate tag to your post.

Comment: That blog post is annoying because he creates a simple model, then changes the requirements and says 'Oh look, the model is broken!'. He then creates his own model, but first states all the requirements. He claims that his modelling technique is superior and thus, inheritance is bad.

Comment: @user1438038 - I am doing with PHP but it should fit for any laguages that have OOP

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is a powerful tool and can achieve code reuse, however it brings potential problems of its own and should be used appropriately.  Because subclasses *depend* on the superclass implementation, inheritance *breaks encapsulation* and can make code more fragile and difficult to maintain.

Achieve the discipline to use inheritance *only* when there really is a "IS A" relationship, eg. a PreferredClient IS A Client ... or ... a MountainBike IS A Bike.  If you are designing a class that doesn't achieve an IS A relationship with an intended superclass, then don't use inheritance.

You can achieve a similar degree of code reuse by using *composition* instead of inheritance.  Instead of making a subclass, incorporate the intended superclass as an attribute of your class.  This allows you to delegate method calls to the contained instance and achieve code reuse.

For your code example, a suggested code decomposition might be this:

```
class MonthTimeCard {

    Month myMonth;

    MonthTimeCard(Month month) { myMonth = month; }

    private function setPrivateVarsByUserInput()  {
        // calls to myMonth
    }

}

Class MonthReport {
    // calls to myMonth
}

Class Month {
    $this->month_from_input = ...

    $this->date_from = ...
    $this->date_to = ...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the way you gave. But then how do I access private variables in Month from MonthTimeCard - directly or by getter functions? And then I will have to use $this->month->getDateFrom() everywhere in my code of MonthTimeCard, similar as I gave example of $this->data->date_from, which looks weird, but if thats best solution, then I can do it.

Comment: Also I can force is-a relationship by some fancy or creative naming, MonthTimeCard is a MonthWorkData :D But probably that is not good. Or maybe it is? And from my few years experience I do not remember the case when inheritance made code difficult to maintain.

Comment: Changing the name of a class to speciously resemble an "IS A" relationship is a way of achieving a superficial adherence to the rule while ignoring the spirit of the rule.  Class A either is a B, or it isn't (no matter what its name is).

Comment: *"But then how do I access private variables in Month from MonthTimeCard "* ... instance fields must always be private (with a few exceptions).  They are implementation details of your class and you should keep them hidden from other classes.  Use accessor methods from other objects to get at your class's data.

Comment: in this case I do not need to change name, but I need to create parent class if I am going to use this approach.

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance.  If two classes don't have an "is a" relationship, then it should never be necessary to use inheritance to achieve code reuse.  Never.

Answer (score 0):

If `MonthTimeCard` and `MonthReport` do not logically extend each other (such as `Dog` and `Cat` are sub types of `Animal`), its not a good idea to use inheritance here anyway.

Besides that, if you do the same validation at multiple locations, you could introduce a standalone `DateValidator` class and use that whenever required.

```
public class DateValidator {

  public static boolean validate(final String dateString) {
    return ...; // TODO: Validate user input here
  }

}
```

Comment: Those do not extend each other, they would extend another class, like Dog extends Animal. And in Animal class I would put validation and private vairable initialisation. In your example - validation is ok, but problem is with setting multiple variables which values are generated from user input using exactly same logic.

Comment: If the classes have nothing in common from a logical perspective, don't make them extend the same base class. Initialization is done per-instance, so usually you wouldn't want to share code for initialization. If you really have a lot of properties and want to ease initialization, make yourself familiar with the [Prototype Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). But from your requirements, its not the right tool. Stick with each class having its own ``init()`` method and let them share a ``DateValidator`` to parse user input.